# Laravel - Many To Many return child records filtered

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a User model which has a M:M relationship with Role model (I use roles_user intermediate table for M:M relationship)

The intermediate table has a column "Active" which defines which of the multiple roles assigned to a User is the active one.

So, I'm trying to retrieve a User with all the relationships it has an also only the active role.

For that, I'm executing the following code https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence:

```
public function index()
    {    
        $users = User::whereHas('roles', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('active', true); 
        })->get();            
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            dd($user->roles);
        }
        
        return view('pages.admin.users.index', compact('users'));
    }
```

When I dd the collection, I have the 5 records in intermediate table and not just the active one which I'm filtering:

[image]

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify how you want to load the relationship:

This gets users that have atleast one "active" role

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('active', true); 
        })->get();
```

However, this line loads all roles regardless of their status.
`dd($user->roles);`

What you need is to get all users that have atleast one active role, and load only active roles on that user:

```
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function (Builder $query) {
            $query->where('active', true); 
        })
        ->with(['roles' => function($query) {
            $query->where('active', true);
        }])
        ->get();
```